# Objects garbage collected in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, junit

I have a simple JUnit test

```
@Test
public void validateMoney() throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/IndividualMoney.json");
    Money money = mapper.readValue(fileStream, Money.class);
    List<Person> people = personService.execute(money);
```

Whenever I run debug on java Oxygen in Linux and try to access the people List I get `com.sun.jdi.objectcollectedexception` occurred while retrieving the value. I read similar problems and one of the solutions was to uncheck window/preferences/debug Show method result after a step operation I unchecked it, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You could use (invoke something on) the people list in order to make sure it does not get GCed.

```
List<Person> people = personService.execute(money);
people.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now, a debug flag on `people.forEach(System.out::println)` should allow you to browse through the `people` list.

Does this fix your issue?